# set variable to function value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function

Im attempting to set this variable as a function, and set the variable's value to that function's output, but i just can't put my finger on how to grab the output correctly:

```
var prev = activeSection.prevAll();

var about = prev.each(function(){ 
     $(this).data('about');
})
```

Now the `.data` func's value is the value i want to set the `about` var to, however when i log the `about` var, i just get all the elements of the `prev` var, not the `.data('about')` of each of them, which i desire.

I know I'm off by something so minute... suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery `.each` function you are using just iterates over the elements. You're not adding them to a list, so nothing is happening with your value.

You would modify your existing code as follows to add your values to an array:

```
var prev = activeSection.prevAll();

var about = [];
prev.each(function(){ 
     about.push($(this).data('about'));
});
```

Alternatively, you can use a jQuery `map` as adeneo noted, or you can do this in a non-jQuery `forEach` loop.

```
var prev = activeSection.prevAll();

var about = [];
prev.forEach(function() {
  var val = $(this).data('about');
  about.push(val);
});
```

Comment: great options here! appreciate it

Comment: what if i would want to check if a certain element has a class matching any of the returns in the array?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to map the data values to get an array of values

```
var prev = activeSection.prevAll();

var about = prev.map(function(){ 
     return $(this).data('about');
}).get();
```

Comment: great! very simple! wish i can accept both answers :(

Comment: what if i would want to check if a certain element has a class matching any of the returns in the array?